# Invoking of GET-Method fails due to {"message":"Missing Authentication Token}

Tags: get, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to invoke an API Gateway HTTP Endpoint with a GET-Method using the JavaScript SDK and AWS Cognito for Authorization.

Accessing the API Method fails with the error: {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}. I've checked the request headers and indeed no token was added by cognito. Cognito authentification is working flawless with a POST-Method located in the same API. The only difference (I know about) is that Cognito should be using the unauthorized-role for the GET-Method.

Here is the code I'm use for invoking the GET-Method.

```
 var apigGetClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
        accessKey: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId,
        secretKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken,
        region: 'eu-central-1'
    });
    var params = {
        // This is where any modeled request parameters should be added.
        // The key is the parameter name, as it is defined in the API in API Gateway.
        "param1": valueOfParam1,
    };
    var body = {
        // This is were the body of the request will be placed.
    };
    var additionalParams = {
        // If there are any unmodeled query parameters or headers that must be
        //   sent with the request, add them here.
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        queryParams: {}
    };
    apigGetClient.rootGet(params, body, additionalParams).then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Why is my GET-Request not signed and what do I have to change in order to invoke the GET-Method properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you double check that the deployed API is correctly defining the GET method and the resource? You would get "Missing Authentication Token" when calling non-existent paths as well.

Comment: I checked the API with Postman and it's working just fine. My workaround for the moment is to disable IAM Auth on the GET method.

I'm somehow suspecting a timing problem in corresponding with Cognito and API Gateway - but I'm unsure how to evaluate this.

Comment: Cognito does not "add" the token as such, the token is calculated by the client using the accessKey, secretKey and the token you provided it in the first few lines of your code. Could you confirm 2 things - check the IAM policy to make sure you have the permissions to actually call this method. Also, enable Cloudwatch logs for your stage and check to see what headers you get for this request.

Comment: You can get this if you are requesting the wrong url as well.